# Including lesser number of decimal points from the list written in scientific notation

Tags: python

Suppose you have a list of values as given bellow:
`list_1 = [1.3846881856127702e-05, 8.253583720918556e-07, 5.099125943708316e-08, 3.1775544417911306e-09, 1.9845003418339502e-10]`

I would like to know whether there is a way to obtain the same list with fewer decimal places? Something like `4`.
I know that there is an option of writing it as,

`list_1=[ '%.2f' % elem for elem in list_1 ]` but since the original values are much smaller, then it will only display zeros.

What I would like to have is something like:
`list_1 = [1.3846e-05 , 8.2535e-07....]`

Comment: By "obtain" are you interested in the display or do you actually want to round the floats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
list_1 = [float('{:0.4e}'.format(i)) for i in list_1]
```

Comment: It helps to mention why.